# How to keep the filters from DataTables after a Back/Forward or Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

*We're using DataTables as our table, and we're having a problem/disagreement with somehow keeping the history of filters that were applied to the table before, so that users can back/forth and refresh through these.*

*Now, one solution that was proposed was that I keep the filters string in the URL, and pass it around as a GET request, which would work well with back/forth and refresh. But as I have very customized filtering options (nested groups of filters), the filter string gets quite long, actually too long to be able to pass it with the GET request because of the length limit.*

*So as GET is out of the question, the obvious solution would be a POST request, and this is what we can't agree upon.*

**First solution** is to use the POST request, and get the "annoying" popup every time we try to go back/forth or refresh. We also break the POST/Redirect/GET pattern that we use throughout the site, since there will be no GET.

**Pros:**

- Simple solution
- No second requests to the server
- No additional database request
- No additional database data
- Only save the filter to the database when you choose to, so that you can re-apply it whenever you want

**Cons:**

- Breaks the POST/Redirect/GET pattern
- Having to push POST data with pushState (history.js)
- How to get refresh to work?

**Second solution** is to use the POST request, server side saves the data in the DB, gets an ID for requesting the saved data, returns it, and the client then does a GET request with this ID, which the server side matches back to the data, returning the right filter, thus retaining the POST/Redirect/GET pattern. This solution makes two requests and saves every filter that users use to the database. Each user would have only a limited number of 'history' filters saved in the database, the older ones getting removed as new ones are applied. Basically the server side would shorten your URL by saving the long data to the database, like an URL shortening site does.

**Pros:**

- Keeps the POST/Redirect/GET pattern
- No popup messages when going back/forth and refreshing the page due to the post data being sent again

**Cons:**

- Complicated solution
- Additional request to the server
- Additional request to the database
- A lot of data in the database that will not be used unless the user goes back/forth or refreshes the page

**A third solution would be very welcome, or pick one of the above and ideally explain why.**

Answer (score 0):

This is a fleeting thought i just had...you can save state of length, filtering, pagination and sorting by using bStateSave http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

My thought was, theoretically you could save the cookie generated by datatables.js into a database table, like you mention in the second solution, but the request only has to happen each time you want to overwrite the current filter, replacing the current cookie with the previous "history" cookie

Comment: We did think about the cookie route also, but yesterday we decided to go back to the GET request, and optimize it to make it work. Which we succeeded with minifying everything sent to the server, so now even making a long filter still won't reach the GET length limit. We used a JSON minifyer and then did some preprocessing ourselves to make it even smaller.